# Need coordinate of selected item in Win32 ListBox

Tags: c, winapi, listbox, ownerdrawn

[image: Current DXGL Config dialog, goals for next version]

I have a listbox made in Win32 .  What I want to do is to somehow obtain the coordinates, from the top left of the control to the selected item, so I can place a control over the selection in order to adjust a setting.

At the same time, I need to figure the height of an ordinary combobox in order to set the thickness of the list items; should I just run GetWindowRect() on the combobox (which will be hidden until the list item is activated) and put the height into the WM_MEASUREITEM message?

Comment: [`LB_GETITEMRECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/lb-getitemrect). For the combobox, your solution sounds reasonable.

Comment: This will get proper coordinates for owner draw variable listboxes too?

Comment: @William yes. Even an owner-drawn ListBox still needs to know where each items is located and what it's dimensions are. That is what `LB_GETITEMRECT` returns

Comment: Thanks!  I just tested it by adding a line of code in my existing listbox and watching the debugger, and it looks good!